# debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog

Tags: mysql, json, ubuntu, packer

I am building my own ubuntu VM with [packer](http://packer.io) to host on [Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/) and I'm using the `packer build template.json` to test if it will be a success if I was to use `packer push template.json` I am getting this error when the I run the [mysql.sh](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/blob/master/scripts/mysql.sh) script.

```
virtualbox-iso: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
    virtualbox-iso: Configuring mysql-server-5.6
    virtualbox-iso: ----------------------------
    virtualbox-iso:
    virtualbox-iso: While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the
    virtualbox-iso: MySQL administrative "root" user.
    virtualbox-iso:
    virtualbox-iso: If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.
    virtualbox-iso:
```

What is it that I'm missing with `debconf:`

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to answer dialog questions when installing under docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466255/is-it-possible-to-answer-dialog-questions-when-installing-under-docker)

Answer (score 13):

can you add

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
```

before you run your script

Comment: No success. Ive seen this in my research about this issue and it still hasn't work

Answer (score 3):

Running the following fixed the issue for me:

```
echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: I'd recommend to run `debconf-show debconf` to see the default so that it helps to restore the default, if something happens while executing the above.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... just a wild guess, from looking at the mysql.sh script, but shouldn't lines 22 & 23 also take into account the above if statement?

The `mysql_package` has changed name, so the selections in your debconf should probably be `mysql-server-5.6` instead of `mysql-server` if [ $2 == "5.6" ]  (which I believe is true in your case, as can be seen from your log  ; )