# How to include Webots in a Docker container build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, webots

I want to add Webots to my Dockerfile, but I'm running into an issue. My current manual installation steps (from [here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/installation-procedure#installing-the-debian-package-with-the-advanced-packaging-tool-apt)) are:

```
$ # launch my Docker container without Webots
$ wget -qO- https://cyberbotics.com/Cyberbotics.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://cyberbotics.com/debian/ binary-amd64/'
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install webots
$ # now I have a Docker container with Webots
```

I want to include this process in the build of the Docker container. I can't just use the same steps in `Dockerfile` though, because while webots is installing, it prompts for some stdin responses asking for the keyboard's country of origin. Since Docker doesn't listen to stdin while building, I have no way to answer these prompts. I tried piping `echo` output like so, but it **doesn't work**:

```
# Install Webots (a robot simulator)
RUN wget -qO- https://cyberbotics.com/Cyberbotics.asc | sudo apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y \
               software-properties-common \
               libxtst6
RUN sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://cyberbotics.com/debian/ binary-amd64/'
RUN apt-get update && echo 31 1 | sudo apt-get install -y \
               webots  # the echo fills the "keyboard country of origin" prompts
```

How can I get Webots included in the Docker container? I don't want to just use someone else's container (e.g. [cyberbotics/webots-docker](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots-docker)), since I need to add other things to the container, like ROS2.

Comment: why don't you just copy and edit https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile?

Comment: Does setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` as described in [Is it possible to answer dialog questions when installing under docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466255/is-it-possible-to-answer-dialog-questions-when-installing-under-docker) help?  (You don't need `sudo` here at all; the Dockerfile should run as root by default.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this answer is incorrect. `FROM` doesn't work like this, and only the last `FROM` statement will be utilized.

Original answer:

It turns out to be simpler than I expected. You can include more than one `FROM $IMAGE` statement in a Dockerfile to combine base images. Here's a sample explaining what I did (note that *all* the `ARG` statements must come before the first `FROM` statement):

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE_WEBOTS=cyberbotics/webots:R2021a-ubuntu20.04
ARG IMAGE2=other/image:latest

FROM $BASE_IMAGE_WEBOTS AS base
FROM $IMAGE2 AS image2

# other things needed
```