# "apt update" fails in jupyter/tensorflow-notebook CLI

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, containers, apt

I'm running a jupyter/tensorflow-notebook container and I need to install a library which needs requires an `apt update`  followed by an `apt install build-essential` prior to installation.

When I run the command in the CLI for the container I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                        
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                  
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#
```

I was hoping someone may have some insight or advice to offer as I'm completely lost with this one.

I'm pulling what little hair I have out..!

Comment: I think it has something to do with your internet access in the jupyter notebook, you need to go ahead and enable internet access to the docker container you are working in, in order to do so, please go ahead and check docker docs on how to enable internet access. This Might Help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give that a shot. Appreciated.

Comment: @7royboy have you solved this issue? It happens to me too

Comment: May you include in your Dockerfile a line such `RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections` It caused this problem to me (with ubuntu 20, while being needed with ubuntu 18 due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755549/997979 )

Comment: Just by way of an update, I ended up running in a local environment as I couldn't find a fix.